How does PowerShell simulate mouse clicks? I used the following code but got an error
I used the following code but got an error
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class MouseHelper {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }
}
"@

function Get-CursorPos {
    $point = [MouseHelper]::POINT{}
    [MouseHelper]::GetCursorPos([ref]$point) | Out-Null
    return $point
}

function Drag-And-Drop {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [int]$startX,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [int]$startY,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [int]$endX,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [int]$endY
    )

    $cursorPos = Get-CursorPos
    $currentX = $cursorPos.X
    $currentY = $cursorPos.Y

    [MouseHelper]::SetCursorPos($startX, $startY)
    [MouseHelper]::mouse_event(0x0002, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    [MouseHelper]::SetCursorPos($endX, $endY)
    [MouseHelper]::mouse_event(0x0004, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    [MouseHelper]::SetCursorPos($currentX, $currentY)
}

Drag-And-Drop -startX 100 -startY 100 -endX 200 -endY 200

The following is the error message
The method call failed because [MouseHelper] does not contain a method named "POINT". Location C:\Users\KKKK\powercat-master\shubiao.ps1:24 Char: 5

$point = [MouseHelper]::POINT{}



CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException

FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Cannot apply [ref] to a variable that does not exist. Location C:\Users\KKKK\powercat-master\shubiao.ps1:25 Characters: 5

[MouseHelper]::GetCursorPos([ref]$point) | Out-Null

~~ ...

I hope to be able to run the simulated mouse click correctly, and I can use other code.
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
“It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.”
Oh, I am speechless. I have almost finished adding

For the first error, try $point = [MouseHelper.POINT]::new().  It should also fix the second error as a side-effect as well…

it would be better without repeating phrases

You're using the wrong syntax to refer to the nested POINT type. To refer to the type itself, use the form [Namespace.EnclosingType+NestedType], then call the static new method to allocate a new instance:
$point = [MouseHelper+POINT]::new()

